# getting birth_day=Null from facebook API's

Tags: iphone, ios

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"select uid,name,birthday_date from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())", @"query",
                                nil];
[[StaticFacebook getFacebook] requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                       andParams: params
                   andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                     andDelegate: self]
```

;

i am using the above code to get friends info.....
but the problem is that i am getting `birth_day="null"`
please sugget me the solution.......
thaks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have requested the proper access permissions to retrieve the birthday field.

`user_birthday - Provides access to the birthday with year as the birthday property`

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Access birthday permission like this  ..

```
[facebookObj authorize:App_ID permissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"offline_access",@"publish_stream",@"user_birthday",@"user_events",@"read_stream",@"friends_likes", nil] delegate:self];
```